# Python File operation get error : ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, csv

I'm newbie in python. I'm trying to store data in `.csv` file, but when I run my program I get the following error:

```
Name: Msc Id: A100
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./python.py", line 29, in <module>
    obj.writeInCsvFile()
  File "./python.py", line 24, in writeInCsvFile
    fp.write(column)    
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

My code is here:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv

class MyClass:
        Name = ''
        Id = ''

        def __init__(self, name, id):
                self.Name = name
                self.Id = id

        def printData(self):
                print "Name:", self.Name, "Id:", self.Id

        def writeInCsvFile(self):
                with open("file.csv", "wb") as fp:
                        wr = csv.writer(fp)

                        data = [["Msc", "Ijp"], ["10", "20"], ["50", "60"]]

                for row in data:
                        for column in row:
                                fp.write(column)
                                fp.write("\t")

obj = MyClass("Msc", 'A100')
obj.printData()
obj.writeInCsvFile()
```

Someone help me. Thank in Advance.

Comment: Indentation problem. Indent `for row in data` and the corresponding lines beneath it right one level.

Comment: Next advice: Follow the _Style Guide for Python Code_ and use [4 spaces per indentation level](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `for` loop is not indented inside the `with` block. Indent them like this:

```
    def writeInCsvFile(self):
            with open("file.csv", "wb") as fp:
                    wr = csv.writer(fp)

                    data = [["Msc", "Ijp"], ["10", "20"], ["50", "60"]]

                    for row in data:
                            for column in row:
                                    fp.write(column)
                                    fp.write("\t")
```